# how to get inputs from a html form and store in the database in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, forms

Can someone explain it step by step. Videos and tutorials found on web do not give a clear understanding about the procedure.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart

Comment: Downvotes are likely for showing zero effort. The quickstart @Laerte links goes through everything you need to do from start to finish, and is quite prominent in the docs. You should strongly consider at least skimming the documentation before working in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of the model class related to the data table
eg :
//creating a patient object to add a row to patients table
$patient = new Patient();

Assign the values

```
    //assign relavant values related to a patient in patients table
    $patient->user_id = $user->id;
    $patient->firstName = $request['firstName'];
    $patient->lastName = $request['lastName'];
    $patient->gender = $request['gender'];
    $patient->gender = 'male';
    $patient->birthYear = $request['birthYear'];
    $patient->telephoneNo = $request['contactNo'];
    $patient->locale = $request['locale'];
    $patient->bloodType = $request['bloodGroup'];
```

Call save() method.

```
    //this will save a patient's record to the patients table
    $patient->save();
```